# Parallel execution policies in C++ 17

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, execution

I have recently started using/learning some of the new features of C++17 to achieve parallelism.

I followed the code (listed below) more or less adapted from the C++17 cookbook (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c17-stl-cookbook/9781787120495/).

But irrespective of whether I use 'execution::par' or 'execution::seq' there seems to be no difference in execution times (see output further below).

---code---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

static bool odd(int n) { return ((n % 2)==0); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arg1 = -1;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        arg1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    std::time_t result1 = std::time(nullptr);
    
    vector<int> d(50000000);

    mt19937 gen;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 100000);
    auto rand_num([=]() mutable { return dis(gen); });

    if (arg1 == 1)
    {
        generate(execution::par, begin(d), end(d), rand_num);

        auto odds(count_if(execution::par, begin(d), end(d), odd));
        cout << (100.0 * odds / d.size()) << "% of the numbers are odd.\n";
    }
    else if(arg1 == 2)
    {
        generate(execution::seq, begin(d), end(d), rand_num);

        auto odds(count_if(execution::seq, begin(d), end(d), odd));
        cout << (100.0 * odds / d.size()) << "% of the numbers are odd.\n";
    }   
    else
    {
        cout << "Missing argument..";
    }
    std::time_t result2 = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "\t\n" << result2-result1 << " (seconds)\n";
}
```

---

I am using Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.8.8. Some of the compile/build options are as follows:

*/JMC /GS /Qpar /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /EHsc /nologo /diagnostics:classic*

----the output I get ----

> **>stlpar.exe 1**
>
> 49.9995% of the numbers are odd.
>
> 16 (seconds)
>
> **>stlpar.exe 2**
>
> 49.9995% of the numbers are odd.
>
> 16 (seconds)
>
> **>**

I expect that running with argument 1 should use execution::par and the time should be noticeably less compared to when run with argument 2 that switches to 'execution::seq'.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 15.8 `generate` is [not implemented as a parallel function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/09/11/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/). So if the time for the code is dominated by the `generate` function, there will be no significant difference in the execution time of your sample code.

Also, it is good practice to use a high resolution timer:

```
#include <chrono>
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip, Is it the same with Count_if? I would expect at least 1-2 second difference with 50000000 elements.

Comment: `count_if` is implemented in that version of VS. However, I'd expect that the random number generator to dominate the execution time, so even when the odd number evaluation is parallelized, there would not be a noticeable reduction in the overall timing.